# How to solve the problem of Android app link verification failed?

Tags: android

I followed this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) to upload my assetlinks.json file to server, and it can be browsed by url like https://host/.well-known/assetlinks.json. However when I tested it using this [tool](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and got an error "No app deep linking permission found for xxx at xxx" with json response as:

{
"maxAge": "599.999999805s",
"debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: unavailable: Error fetching statements from https://host./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://host/.well-known/assetlinks.json'): URL_ERROR/3 [14] while fetching Web statements from https://host./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://host/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your query\n",
"errorCode": [
"ERROR_CODE_FETCH_ERROR"
]
}

Is there any solution for this issue? Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same thing :(

Comment: @dchappelle Well in my case, it's simply because i deploy the website in the intranet of my company where google's verification service can not find it.

Comment: Thanks @Yuki N I had the same issue